# Pig Latin Partition By clause

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What is the use of "Partition By" clause in Pig Latin?

Also please provide an example usage.

Does it allow only custom partition or allows partition by column?

Answer (score 2):

**What is the use of "Partition By" clause in Pig Latin?**

This allows you to set the **Partitioner** of your choice. Pig uses the default one i'e HashPartitioner except for **order** and **skew join**. But sometimes you might wanna have your own implementation to enhance the performance. **Partition By** helps there.

**Also please provide an example usage.**

```
DATA = LOAD '/inputs/demo.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as (no:int, name:chararray);
PARTITIONED = GROUP DATA by name PARTITION BY org.apache.pig.test.utils.SimpleCustomPartitioner parallel 2;
```

**Does it allow only custom partition or allows partition by column?**

It is just to specify custom partitioners and not to partition directly based on some field.

See **[PIG-282](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-282)** for more details.